# How to see column description in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I am using SQL Server Management Studio to make query of data. After making a query, how can I find more information of the column names? For example, it is not easy to understand what LOC_NUM_ABC indicates. Is there a way that I could get the information of columns' names? For example: LOC_NUM_ABC means number of locations with product ABC.

Thanks

Comment: Thats not stored anywhere, by default anyway, when creating a table you are not required to provide a description of what a column does. Your in-house database design document(s) should contain that.

Comment: ...or source code / repo, or extended properties as a last resort, or all of the above. Nobody (including Microsoft) can programmatically determine, without meaningful context, that `LOC_NUM_ABC` means "number of locations with product ABC." It could just as easily be "what percentage of locusts become numb after drinking Mercedes ABC suspension fluid." Now, if you _have_ that context stored somewhere, we'd have to know where that is to provide any kind of guidance - but also SSMS is a closed system, so adding it to tooltips in grids or query windows is not an easy thing to do either.

Comment: Why on earth people can write proper column names is beyond me. What's wrong with `NumLocations_ProductABC`? And ALL-CAPS is just pure eye-strain

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for Extended Properties techniques similar to those described in:

- [Towards the Self-Documenting SQL Server Database](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/tools-sql-server/towards-the-self-documenting-sql-server-database/)

For example:

```sql
create table dbo.Stuffs (
  LOC_NUM_ABC int
);

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty
    @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'A table with things about the stuffs',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = [dbo],
    @level1type = N'TABLE',  @level1name = N'Stuffs';

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty
    @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'The number of locations with stuffs',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = [dbo],
    @level1type = N'TABLE',  @level1name = N'Stuffs',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN', @level2name = N'LOC_NUM_ABC';
```

Then you can query the values using:

```sql
select value
from fn_listextendedproperty('MS_Description', 'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'Stuffs', default, default);
```

| value |
| --- |
| A table with things about the stuffs |

Or:

```sql
select value
from fn_listextendedproperty('MS_Description', 'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'Stuffs', 'column', 'LOC_NUM_ABC');
```

| value |
| --- |
| The number of locations with stuffs |

Perhaps ironically, the documentation of the documentation stored procedures [sp_addextendedproperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql), [sp_updateextendedproperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-updateextendedproperty-transact-sql), [sp_dropextendedproperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-dropextendedproperty-transact-sql) and [sys.fn_listextendedproperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-listextendedproperty-transact-sql) is fairly scant since there's no official table (that I can find) describing the Microsoft usages of `@name` parameter values and their definitions.